# django collectstatic: How to keep the project structure?

Tags: python, django

Currently, collecstatic gathers all files of the project's Apps in one directory (STATIC_ROOT).

What should be done to keep the project structure for the static files:
STATIC_ROOT/App1
..
STATIC_ROOT/Appn
STATIC_ROOT/App3

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation [recommends namespacing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/):

> ### Static file namespacing
>
> Now we *might* be able to get away with putting our static files directly in `my_app/static/` (rather than creating another `my_app` subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a *different* application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by *namespacing* them. That is, by putting those static files inside *another* directory named for the application itself.

Make sure to create an inner directory named after your app and put your files in there, e.g.

- `my_app/`

  - `static/`

    - `my_app/` ← This directory

      - `file1`
      - `file1`
      - ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you chris,
I find exactly the solution as indicated here: [How should I structure my static app files in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636217/how-should-i-structure-my-static-app-files-in-django)

I have just replace STATICDIR_FILES by :

```
    STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```